# Optimizing function for search

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a search filter in my application. I would like to optimize this code, because it has too much lines of code. How change it so,it will work the same but with less code?

```
function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, th, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            th = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[0]; // for column one
            th1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[1];
            th2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[2];
            th3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[3];
            th4 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[4];
            th5 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[5];
            th6 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[6];
            th7 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[7];
            th8 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[8];
            th9 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[9];// for column two
            /* columns for search*/
            if (th) {
                if ( (th.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th3.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th4.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th5.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th6.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th7.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th8.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) || (th9.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)  )  {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add something to your question that explains what your code does, and what you hope it does after refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

Using hidden and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)  will be much shorter

I use `find` instead of `some` for semantic reasons.

```
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll("#MyTable tbody tr")
  trs.forEach(tr => {
    const hide = filter && 
      ![...tr.querySelectorAll("th")]                              // none of the cells 
        .find(th => th.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter));// contains filter
    tr.hidden = hide;
  })
})
```

Example

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr")
  trs.forEach(tr => {
    const hide = filter && ![...tr.querySelectorAll("td")].find(td => td.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter))
    tr.hidden = hide;
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Filter" title="Filter text" autocomplete="off" />
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>Seven</td>
      <td>Eight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Nine</td>
      <td>Ten</td>
      <td>Eleven</td>
      <td>Twelve</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `filter()` then check length

Answer (score 0):

You can also search in table by this way:

```
//search input id
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    //tableStudentbody table id
        $("#tableStudentbody tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag?